# UILabel sizeToFit in ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uilabel

I am getting a weird behaviour of UILabel in ScrollView. I am assigning dynamic text to the UILabel and using sizeToFit, I can log the new size which seems to change correctly after assigning text but I can't see the changed size reflected in both the simulator and the real device. This is the log before assigning and after assigning text

```
--txt Frame {{15, 325}, {291, 36}}
--txt Frame1 {{15, 296}, {291, 446.5}}
```

As you can see, the size (height) changes though I don't see the changes on device and simulator. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this after sizeToFit()

```
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

`override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.myLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `numberOfLines` property for that label Before use the `sizeToFit` method.

may be that also cause the problem.

may be the label frame is change but label's `numberOfLines` property is set to 1 so it display only 1 line.

try to set the number of lines property before using `sizeToFit` method, like

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
```

this will set the all the text for any number of line in label.
Hope it will Help you.

Comment: I have done that already but still not working. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with different approaches, I ended up manually extending the height of the contentView in IB myself. Its not the most elegant solution but it works for now :(